# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's') While trying to upload excel file to db

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am attending to upload and save the excel values to the database. At the point of saving the values to db I got the error `Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')` I am guessing the problem could be EF related but I still can't pinpoint what to do to fix it.

If there is no empty column the excel, the excel will successfully upload and saved to db.  But how do I handle if some excel columns are empty?

Some columns could me empty that is why I have to make some nullable.

I don't know what I am doing wrong

```
ex.StackTrace:

  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Int64.Parse(String s)
   at LoanWarehouse.Controllers.AccountUploadController.<SaveCustomerUpload>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\Users\DELL\source....\Controllers\UploadController.cs:line 409
```

Here is the method that is extracting values and saving to db

```
   public async Task<Response> SaveCustomerUpload(int UploadId, ExcelWorksheet workSheet, int rowSize)
        {
            Response response = new Response();
            response.IsSuccessful = true;

            List<Customer> CustomerDatalist = new List<Customer>();

            //skip first row for column header
            for (int i = 2; i <= rowSize; i++)
            {
                try
                {

                    CustomerDatalist.Add(new Customer
                    {
                        CustId = long.Parse(workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString()),
                        FirstName_CompanyName = workSheet.Cells[i, 2].Value.ToString(),
                        MiddleName = workSheet.Cells[i, 3].Value.ToString(),
                        Gender = workSheet?.Cells[i, 4]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        FatherName = workSheet?.Cells[i, 5]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        MotherName = workSheet?.Cells[i, 6]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        DateOfBirth = null,
                        BVN = long.Parse(workSheet?.Cells[i, 8]?.Value?.ToString()),
                        EmailAddress = workSheet?.Cells[i, 9]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        OfficeNumber = workSheet?.Cells[i, 10]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        Nationality = workSheet?.Cells[i, 11]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        PlaceOfBirth = workSheet?.Cells[i, 12]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        MaritalStatus = workSheet?.Cells[i, 13]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        SpouseName = workSheet?.Cells[i, 14]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        TelephoneNo = workSheet?.Cells[i, 15]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        MobileNo = workSheet?.Cells[i, 16]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        Address = workSheet?.Cells[i, 17]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        OfficeEmailAddress = workSheet?.Cells[i, 18]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        FaxNumber = workSheet?.Cells[i, 19]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        WebsiteURL = workSheet?.Cells[i, 20]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        RelatedComapany = workSheet?.Cells[i, 21]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        LegalConstitution = workSheet?.Cells[i, 22]?.Value?.ToString(),
                        ShareHolder = workSheet?.Cells[i, 22]?.Value?.ToString(),
                    }
                    
                    );
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    response.Message = ex.ToString();
                    response.IsSuccessful = false;
                    logger.Error(ex);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (response.IsSuccessful)
            {
                //save the details for this upload
                await _context.Customer.AddRangeAsync(CustomerDatalist);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                //reverse the initial AccountUpload and delete the details
                var CustomerUpload = await _context.Customer.FindAsync(UploadId);
                _context.Customer.Remove(CustomerUpload);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }


            return response;
        }
```

Comment: I see lots of Value?.toString() And Value.toString(). I recommend debugging them as casting a null to string should throw an exception.

Comment: There is a recommended format for the excel, some columns may be empty because some info may not be available at the time of uploading the excel. I have a method checking the header before they are uploaded.

Comment: If there is no empty column the excel, the excel will successfully upload and saved to db.  But how do I handle if some excel columns are empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can "convert" the null values of the attributes into strings.
Example: CustId = long.Parse(workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString()) **?? ""**

EDIT: Sorry. This don't work because it gives CustId an empty string. But I think this will work. First, create 2 variables outside "CustomerDatalist.Add":

```
string _CustId = workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString()
string _BVN = workSheet.Cells[i, 8].Value.ToString()
```

In the "Add" method change their respective lines to:
CustId = (_CustId == "") ? (int?)null : long.Parse(_CustId),
BVN = (_BVN == "") ? (int?)null : long.Parse(_CustId),

This will assign null values to the attributes if the strings are empty. But it needs that you change a few parameters in the class "CustomerDatalist". Add ? in the definition of the attributes and the object itself:

```
long ?CustId
long ?BVN

public CustomerDatalist(int ?CustId,... ?BVN,...) {}
```

Add '?' made the attributes able to accept null values and if the columns in the DB can accept null values it must work.

Comment: This code will throw an exception when the cell's value is null.

Comment: I got ```OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.Value.get returned null.```

Answer (score -1):

Could you maybe find a workaround converting first the Excel files to CSV files?